# Is it possible to list all user that accessed to specific table

Tags: oracle

Is there a way in Oracle (11) to make a list of users when they were last accessed (select / update / insert or delete) a table or view ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with auditing, but it incurs a performance overhead and does not work retrospectively.

Read the section [Verifying Security Access with Auditing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#DBSEG006) in the [Oracle® Database Security Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/toc.htm).

I'll add that in the majority of cases, somebody in the organisation thinks that this type of auditing is required, but more often than not it is just a misguided requirement.